# How to debug the code to find whether we are getting response from the endpoint url

Tags: rest-api, webservices, debugging, debug-logs

I have written a Api and Iam trying to debug to check we are getting the response. Please advise how to debug it . I did debug the code but in logs i get Status code ok But not the response.

Please find the code below.

```
global class HealthwiseAPI {

    public HealthwiseWrapper getData(){
        //instantiate new http Object
        Http h = new Http();
        // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String endUrl = 'http://carrotcube-healthwise-api.cloudhub.io/healthwise/heartfailure';
        req.setEndpoint(endUrl);
        system.debug(endUrl);   
        req.setMethod('GET'); // Send the request, and return a response
        HttpResponse res; 
        String ResponseBody;
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            res = h.send(req);
            ResponseBody = req.getBody();
        } else {
            StaticResource srObject = [SELECT id,body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'SampleZyncResponse'];
            ResponseBody = srObject.body.toString();             
        }        
        system.debug(ResponseBody);

        HealthwiseWrapper healthwrapper = new HealthwiseWrapper();
        healthwrapper = HealthwiseWrapper.parse(ResponseBody);
        system.debug(healthwrapper);
        try{
            if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){

            }
        } catch(exception e) {

        }
        return healthwrapper;
    }  

}
```

Comment: You should be able to just run a `System.Debug();` method on your `res.getBody();` Also I saw in your code that you are using the request body instead of your response body when you are setting your `ResponseBody` string variable.

Comment: it will be  ResponseBody = res.getBody();

Comment: @Himanshu Hi I have tried something like this still same result  HttpResponse res; 
String ResponseBody;
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
    res = h.send(req);
    ResponseBody = req.getBody();
            system.debug(res);
}

Comment: There's an empty `catch` block in there... those do more harm than good. An empty catch block will effectively hide an exception. If you can't effectively handle an exception in the catch block, it's usually better to surface it (even it it's ugly).

Comment: hi iam getting it now i tried this one it worked System.debug('response----'+res.getBody());

Comment: @SamuelRobert great.. this is what I said :)